# Replace String in Java with regex and replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Is there a simple solution to parse a `String` by using regex in Java?

I have to adapt a HTML page. Therefore I have to parse several strings, e.g.:

```
href="/browse/PJBUGS-911"
=>
href="PJBUGS-911.html"
```

The pattern of the strings is only different corresponding to the ID (e.g. `911`). My first idea looks like this:

```
String input = "";
String output = input.replaceAll("href=\"/browse/PJBUGS\\-[0-9]*\"", "href=\"PJBUGS-???.html\"");
```

I want to replace everything except the ID. How can I do this?

Would be nice if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) substrings that were matched by your pattern, using parentheses. And then you can use the captured things in the replacement with `$n` where `n` is the number of the set of parentheses (counting opening parentheses from left to right). For your example:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("href=\"/browse/PJBUGS-([0-9]*)\"", "href=\"PJBUGS-$1.html\"");
```

Or if you want:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("href=\"/browse/(PJBUGS-[0-9]*)\"", "href=\"$1.html\"");
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer and solution. Works fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

This does not use regexp. But maybe it still solves your problem.

```
output = "href=\"" + input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("/")) + ".html\"";
```

Comment: Don't forget to add ".html" to the end

Comment: Pretty simple and straightforward this is.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes there is. He requires it for his answer.

Comment: I believe `input` is not a single `href="/browse/..."` but a whole HTML file. Hence, the explicit mentioning of `replaceAll` in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And yes you're probably right @m.buettner

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String text = "href=\"/browse/PJBUGS-911\" blahblah href=\"/browse/PJBUGS-111\" " +
                "blahblah href=\"/browse/PJBUGS-34234\"";

        Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("href=\"/browse/(PJBUGS-[0-9]+?)\"");

        Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(text);

        while(mtchr.find())
        {
            String match = mtchr.group(0);
            String insMatch = mtchr.group(1);



            String repl = match.replaceFirst(match, "href=\"" + insMatch + ".html\"");

            System.out.println("orig = <" + match + "> repl = <" + repl + ">");
        }
    }
```

This just shows the regex and replacements, not the final formatted text, which you can get by using `Matcher.replaceAll`:

```
String allRepl = mtchr.replaceAll("href=\"$1.html\"");
```

If just interested in replacing all, you don't need the loop -- I used it just for debugging/showing how regex does business.